# Let $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ be of the form $4k+3$ for $k \geq 0$. Prove there are no integers $x$ and $y$ such that $x^2+y^2=n$.

Tags: solution-verification, proof-explanation

This exercise came up from a book on proof writing. I know it has something to do with number theory, but I'm not familiar with the subject. Nevertheless, I started like this:

***Proof.*** Suppose $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $k \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ such that $n = 4k + 3$. Suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that there are $y, x \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $x^2 + y^2 = n$. Then
$$x^2 + y^2 = 4k + 3.$$
Notice that the right-hand side is always odd, as it can be written as $2(2k+1)+1$. However, the left-hand side may be even if both $x$ and $y$ have the same parity. Thus the equality is not true. *[Is this sufficient to derive a contradiction?]*

If this "proof" is even correct, I feel it is not convincing at all. How should I proceed?

**Edit 1.** Firstly, thank you all for the hints. Based on the hints, I came up with a solution quite similar to one of the answers, but here is how I would write it:

***Proof.*** Suppose $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $k \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ such that $n = 4k + 3$. Suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that there are $y, x \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $x^2 + y^2 = n$. Then
$$x^2 + y^2 = 4k + 3.$$
This implies $x^2 + y^2$ is odd, thus $x^2$ and $y^2$ have opposite parities. Suppose, without loss of generality, that $x^2$ is even and $y^2$ is odd. This implies $x$ and $y$ are even and odd, respectively. Then there are $q, p \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $x^2 = (2q)^2$ and $y^2 = (2q + 1)^2$. Then
$$x^2 + y^2 = (2q)^2 + (2p + 1)^2 = 4q^2 + 4p^2 + 4p + 1 = 4(q^2 + p^2 + p) + 1,$$
where $q^2 + p^2 + p \geq 0$. This contradicts the assumption that $x^2 + y^2$ is of the form $4k+3$ for some $k \geq 0$. Therefore, there are no $y, x \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $x^2 + y^2 = 4k + 3$ for $k \geq 0$.

Comment: No, that is not enough.  The left hand could be even or odd, parity isn't good enough here.

Comment: As a hint:  Try to argue that, if $m$ is odd, then $m^2$ is of the form $4k+1$ for some $k$.  Use that fact to finish the proof.

Comment: So, if $x,y$ have the same parity, you showed that they could not have been equal to $4k+3$ since the LHS would be even but the RHS would be odd.  Now, you still have yet to explore the case of $x,y$ having different parity.  $x^2+y^2$ would be odd in that case... the question is why even in that case it still couldn't be equal to $4k+3$.

Comment: $4k+3$=$3$(mod $4$), $x^2+y^2$=$0,1,2$$\neq$$3$(mod $4$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A clear proof by contradiction**

Suppose for the sake of contradiction, $x^2+y^2=4k+3$. Since $4k+3$ is odd, both $x,y$ can't be odd or even. So, one is even the other is odd. Let, WLOG, $x=2a$ and $y=2b+1$. Then we get that $$(2a)^2+(2b+1)^2=4k+3\\\iff 4a^2+4(b^2+b)+1=4k+3\\\iff 4(a^2+(b^2+b)-k)=2$$ This implies $4\mid 2$. Contradiction!

Answer (score 1):

You got the right idea. If $x,y$ is a pair of even (or odd) numbers, then the sum of their squares is even. If they have opposite parity, observe that a square number is either $0$ mod $4$ or $1$ mod $4$.